# Android: holo button with image

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to anticipate that I'm very noob in programming.
I'm just starting.

I'd like to ask for help to make this button image working. I've already done a research [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2009/08/exercise-load-background-to-imagebutton.html) and within the forum but I couldn't find a similar case.

I'm trying to modify an app and change the buttons
I've created a holo themed button using http: / /android-holo-colors.com

This tool created the following structure.
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5n24.png)

To achieve the goal I'm modifying the activity layout xml where I put the button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGameOverPlayAgain"
        android:text="@string/popupGameOverButtonPlay"
        style="??????" />
```

Here I'm not sure if I need to refer to the style.xml or the styles_apptheme.xml created by the tool

and where to I need to declare the button?

also in the styles_apptheme XML there are two styles

```
 <style name="ButtonAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
  <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
```

```
<style name="ImageButtonAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.ImageButton">
  <item
name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_btn_default_holo_light</item>
```

To which one do I need to refer? "ButtonAppTheme" or "ImageButtonAppTheme"

Hope it's understandable, thanks everyone in advance for the patience and the support.

Answer (score 0):

***How to access styles***

Styles are resource values and as such their value can be accessed all the same, despite the name of the file they are declared in, as long as it is in `/res/values/` folder of your app. Thus it will be all the same if you have your style declarations in two files `styles_apptheme` and `styles` or you merge them in one.

You access the style with its name, not needing to know in whch exactly file it is declared. Thus even with your current file structure you address `ButtonAppTheme` with `style="@style/ButtonAppTheme"`.

***What are styles***

Teh styles declare reusable sets of view attribute values. Declaring a single style like e.g. your `ButtonAppTheme` allows you to use the set of attributes declared in this style sin multiple places without the need of copy-pasting and thus sparing you the need of modifying on multiple places if you decide any of the attrbutes needs a change.

***How to use them***

- Where to place the button - anywhere in your application layouts, where you decide you need to use such a buttlon
- Which of the two style sshould you use - one of them is meant for ordinary buttons, the other is for [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). The first is a button with text label, the second is imege-only button supported by Android. Use whichever of the two is more appropriate for each of your cases. I can speculate that you are interested in plain Buttons.